# Why values in fields disappear after reloading the web page with windows.opener.location.reload(true) in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some **labels** in a web app which have the following properties: personalizable="false" readonly="true" and some values that are read from the database. After I executed a function, I refreshed the page using: **windows.opener.location.reload(true)**. After refreshing, the values are lost. If I use **F5**  for refresh, the values are still kept in the labels. But I need automatically refresh the page after function is executed, not with F5. This needs to work in **Firefox**. How can I solve this?

Comment: sounds like you need to open an issue w/ them

Comment: Can you be more precise? You said you lost the values. That means the values reset to the initial value rather than to the value you have updated or the whole field went blank? Please see that readonly only tells the browser to prevent editing. It doesn't make the changes permanent. The value you have coded in the script will remain there when you reload. You have to use a function to reload the values. If possible update question with relevant parts of your code

Comment: The field become empty.

Comment: Can you post a small example to show the problem? Like the minimum set of code used to reproduce the issue.